# Redirect https to http in Spring

Tags: http, tomcat, https, url-rewriting, redirect

I have configured SSL into my application running on Tomcat using the standard procedures. I have modified the server.xml file and web.xml to enforce the use of https in every request. I am supposed to do one of the 2 things.

1) The redirection that is taking place is a 302 redirect. How can I make this as a 301 redirect? This 302 redirect is not allowing Google robots to crawl my site

OR

2) Use a mechanism wherein the urls that I require to be http, are redirected from https to http.
I know Tomcat cannot automatically redirect from https to http once it is re-directed to http. I have added the following entry in web.xml to enable http access for the url that I require

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecureConnection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>UnsecureConnection</web-resource-name>        
        <url-pattern>/Market/browseMarket.htm</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>    
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>   
</security-constraint>
```

However once Tomcat is redirected to https using the first block, it is unable to redirect back to http even though the second block exists.

I read in some articles to use URLRedirectFilter in the application to achieve. To achieve that, I added the following in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have placed the urlrewrite.xml under WEB-INF, the contents of which are:

```
<urlrewrite>
   <rule>  
          <from>Market/browseMarket.htm</from>  
          <to>http://%{server-name}%{request-uri}</to>  
   </rule>  
</urlrewrite>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I still end up with https on that page.

Can someone help me with one of the above issues with a solution?